# jquery post function returns error only on IE11

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, internet-explorer-11

I am using the script below to post contact form with ajax, it works on all browsers except IE11. I only pasted the piece of code where ie11 behaves different.

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), formValues, function(data)
{
    if ( data == 'success' )
    {
        contactForm.clearForm();
    }
    else
    {
        $alert.addClass('error');
    }
});
```

in IE11 else statement is being executed and form not sended to server. What is wrong with that code?

Comment: What is `data` when you look at it in IE 11's debugger?

Comment: it holds `"error"` value in IE11

Comment: Have you verified that the same data is being posted in IE 11? The response from the server suggests the data is different.